# How to define EKRecurrenceRule to represent 'Every 4 years only on 4th of July'

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekrecurrencerule

I am trying to represent the recurrence rule,

> Every 4 years only on 4th of July.

like this:

```
termin.addRecurrenceRule(EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWithFrequency: .Yearly,
    interval: 4,
    daysOfTheWeek: nil,
    daysOfTheMonth: [NSNumber(int: 4)],
    monthsOfTheYear: [NSNumber(int :7)],
    weeksOfTheYear: nil,
    daysOfTheYear: nil,
    setPositions: nil,
    end: nil))
```

but Apple documentation says:

> daysOfTheMonth: The days of the month that the event occurs, as an array of
>   NSNumber objects. Values can be from 1 to 31 and from -1 to -31. **This
>   parameter is only valid for recurrence rules of type
>   `EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly`**.

Then how can I represent the above mentioned rule with the `EKRecurrenceRule` class?

NB: The answers could be in Swift or Objc.

Comment: What about using a .Monthly with an interval of 48 then?

Comment: @hnh good point, but I could not justify the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "I could not justify the answer"? :-) Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Create an event with a start and end date on the 4th of July and give it a yearly recurrence rule like this:

```
let event = EKEvent(eventStore: self.eventStore)

event.title = title
event.startDate = fourthOfJulyStartDate
event.endDate = fourthOfJulyEndDate
event.recurrenceRules = [EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWithFrequency: .Yearly, interval: 4, end: nil)]
```